# How to set Empty date in dateChooserCombo1?

Tags: java

I'am using dateChooserCombo1 to choose expiry date but. it always have expiry date selected even if the product is nut yet expired. i want to have a dateChooserCombo1 empty value.  how can i set this null?

Comment: What is "dateChooserCombo1"?

Comment: its a netbeans plugin , new datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo();

Answer (score 0):

its in the  **.fxml** code.

Search for 'dateChooserCombo1'. but if u are using SceneBuilder, you can set the value in the properties.